# How to handle resources in JSCH exec correctly?

Tags: java, exception, ssh, io, jsch

I've found [example](https://www.baeldung.com/java-ssh-connection#1-implementation) of ssh connection:

```
 public static void listFolderStructure(String username, String password, 
      String host, int port, String command) throws Exception {
        
        Session session = null;
        ChannelExec channel = null;
        
        try {
            session = new JSch().getSession(username, host, port);
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.connect();
            
            channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
            channel.setCommand(command);
            ByteArrayOutputStream responseStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            channel.setOutputStream(responseStream);
            channel.connect();
            
            while (channel.isConnected()) {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            
            String responseString = new String(responseStream.toByteArray());
            System.out.println(responseString);
        } finally {
            if (session != null) {
                session.disconnect();
            }
            if (channel != null) {
                channel.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
```

I have couple of questions about the code:

1. Is there any reason to call `disconnect` on a channel after seesion is disconnected ?
   looks like [this line](https://github.com/rtyley/jsch/blob/master/src/com/jcraft/jsch/Session.java#L1564) will disconnect all channels

```
    public void disconnect(){
        if(!isConnected) return;
    
        ...
        Channel.disconnect(this);
    
        ...
```

2. Should `session.disconnect()` throw any Runtime Exception ? Should I handle this case ?
3. Example in lib repo also have both(session and channel close) and even not in finally block. Is it correct ?

https://github.com/rtyley/jsch/blob/master/examples/Exec.java#L77

Answer (score 1):

###### 1. You can separate a channel from a session, so it's safer to explicit close the channel

```
Session session = null;
ChannelExec channel = null;
Session session2 = null;
ChannelExec2 channel = null;

try {
  session = new JSch().getSession(username, host, port);
  ...
  channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
  ...
  session2 = new JSch().getSession(username, host, port);
  channel.setSession(session2);
  ...
} finally {
  if (session != null) {
    session.disconnect();
  }
  if (channel != null) {
    channel.disconnect();
  }
}
try {
  channel2 = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
  ...
} finally {
  if (session2 != null) {
    session2.disconnect();
  }
  if (channel2 != null) {
    channel2.disconnect();
  }
}
```

###### 2. `disconnect` calls [close](https://github.com/rtyley/jsch/blob/master/src/com/jcraft/jsch/Channel.java#L341), which may throw an `IOException`.

So to be safe, you should handle this case.

```
Session session = null;
ChannelExec channel = null;
try {
  session = new JSch().getSession(username, host, port);
  ...
  channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
  ...
} catch(Exception ex) {
  ex.printStacktrace();
} finally {
  try {
    if (session != null) {
      session.disconnect();
    }
  } catch(Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
  }
  try {
    if (channel != null) {
     channel.disconnect();
    }
  } catch(Exception e2) {
    e2.printStacktrace();
  }
}
```

###### 3. Examples are often simplified to focus on a use case. So don't take everything in them as gospel.

Comment: It would be better for future googlers to have an example

Comment: BTW in your second example in case if `session.disconnect();` throws exception then `channel.disconnect();` won't be called